# Python Selenium, find by class_name working but find by XPATH not working for same element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

So I'm scrapping TripAdvisor's reviews page for individual hotels, trying to get the number of stars for said hotel.

[TripAdvisor hotel review page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHzIe.jpg)

The HTML for the div where this info is included is this (I don't copy the HTML for the whole page because it's really long and I don't think it's necessary):

```
<div class="drcGn _R MC S4 _a H">
  <span class="fyiTP S2">
    <svg class="TkRkB d H0" viewBox="0 0 120 24" width="80" height="16" aria-label="4.0 of 5 bubbles">
            <path d="M23.37 8.518l-6.587-1.68a1.716 1.716 0 01-.479-.36L12.712.357C12.478.121 12.235.005 12 0c-.235.005-.478.121-.712.356L7.696 6.478c-.121.12-.24.238-.479.36L.63 8.518c-.479.12-.719.601-.6.96 0 .12.121.239.121.239l4.429 5.521c.121.239.241.481.241.601l-.479 7.32c0 .484.36.841.719.841.121 0 .24 0 .36-.119l6.229-2.642c.114 0 .232-.112.351-.117.118.005.236.117.351.117l6.229 2.642c.118.119.237.119.358.119.359 0 .719-.357.719-.841l-.479-7.32c0-.119.12-.361.241-.601l4.429-5.521s.121-.119.121-.239c.12-.36-.121-.84-.6-.96zm24 0l-6.587-1.68a1.716 1.716 0 01-.479-.36L36.712.357C36.478.121 36.235.005 36 0c-.235.005-.478.121-.712.356l-3.592 6.122c-.121.12-.24.238-.479.36l-6.587 1.68c-.479.12-.719.601-.6.96 0 .12.121.239.121.239l4.429 5.521c.121.239.241.481.241.601l-.479 7.32c0 .484.36.841.719.841.121 0 .24 0 .36-.119l6.229-2.642c.114 0 .232-.112.351-.117.118.005.236.117.351.117l6.229 2.642c.118.119.237.119.358.119.359 0 .719-.357.719-.841l-.479-7.32c0-.119.12-.361.241-.601l4.429-5.521s.121-.119.121-.239c.12-.36-.121-.84-.6-.96zm24 0l-6.587-1.68a1.716 1.716 0 01-.479-.36L60.712.357C60.478.121 60.235.005 60 0c-.235.005-.478.121-.712.356l-3.592 6.122c-.121.12-.24.238-.479.36l-6.587 1.68c-.479.12-.719.601-.6.96 0 .12.121.239.121.239l4.429 5.521c.121.239.241.481.241.601l-.479 7.32c0 .484.36.841.719.841.121 0 .24 0 .36-.119l6.229-2.642c.114 0 .232-.112.351-.117.118.005.236.117.351.117l6.229 2.642c.118.119.237.119.358.119.359 0 .719-.357.719-.841l-.479-7.32c0-.119.12-.361.241-.601l4.429-5.521s.121-.119.121-.239c.12-.36-.121-.84-.6-.96zm24 0l-6.587-1.68a1.716 1.716 0 01-.479-.36L84.712.357C84.478.121 84.235.005 84 0c-.235.005-.478.121-.712.356l-3.592 6.122c-.121.12-.24.238-.479.36l-6.587 1.68c-.479.12-.719.601-.6.96 0 .12.121.239.121.239l4.429 5.521c.121.239.241.481.241.601l-.479 7.32c0 .484.36.841.719.841.121 0 .24 0 .36-.119l6.229-2.642c.114 0 .232-.112.351-.117.118.005.236.117.351.117l6.229 2.642c.118.119.237.119.358.119.359 0 .719-.357.719-.841l-.479-7.32c0-.119.12-.361.241-.601l4.429-5.521s.121-.119.121-.239c.12-.36-.121-.84-.6-.96zm24 0l-6.587-1.68a1.716 1.716 0 01-.479-.36L108.712.357C108.478.121 108.235.005 108 0c-.235.005-.478.121-.712.356l-3.592 6.122c-.121.12-.24.238-.479.36l-6.587 1.68c-.479.12-.719.601-.6.96 0 .12.121.239.121.239l4.429 5.521c.121.239.241.481.241.601l-.479 7.32c0 .484.36.841.719.841.121 0 .24 0 .36-.119l6.229-2.642c.114 0 .232-.112.351-.117.118.005.236.117.351.117l6.229 2.642c.118.119.237.119.358.119.359 0 .719-.357.719-.841l-.479-7.32c0-.119.12-.361.241-.601l4.429-5.521s.121-.119.121-.239c.12-.36-.121-.84-.6-.96z"></path><path class="cenTm" d="M23.37 8.518l-6.587-1.68a1.716 1.716 0 01-.479-.36L12.712.357C12.478.121 12.235.005 12 0c-.235.005-.478.121-.712.356L7.696 6.478c-.121.12-.24.238-.479.36L.63 8.518c-.479.12-.719.601-.6.96 0 .12.121.239.121.239l4.429 5.521c.121.239.241.481.241.601l-.479 7.32c0 .484.36.841.719.841.121 0 .24 0 .36-.119l6.229-2.642c.114 0 .232-.112.351-.117.118.005.236.117.351.117l6.229 2.642c.118.119.237.119.358.119.359 0 .719-.357.719-.841l-.479-7.32c0-.119.12-.361.241-.601l4.429-5.521s.121-.119.121-.239c.12-.36-.121-.84-.6-.96zm24 0l-6.587-1.68a1.716 1.716 0 01-.479-.36L36.712.357C36.478.121 36.235.005 36 0c-.235.005-.478.121-.712.356l-3.592 6.122c-.121.12-.24.238-.479.36l-6.587 1.68c-.479.12-.719.601-.6.96 0 .12.121.239.121.239l4.429 5.521c.121.239.241.481.241.601l-.479 7.32c0 .484.36.841.719.841.121 0 .24 0 .36-.119l6.229-2.642c.114 0 .232-.112.351-.117.118.005.236.117.351.117l6.229 2.642c.118.119.237.119.358.119.359 0 .719-.357.719-.841l-.479-7.32c0-.119.12-.361.241-.601l4.429-5.521s.121-.119.121-.239c.12-.36-.121-.84-.6-.96zm24 0l-6.587-1.68a1.716 1.716 0 01-.479-.36L60.712.357C60.478.121 60.235.005 60 0c-.235.005-.478.121-.712.356l-3.592 6.122c-.121.12-.24.238-.479.36l-6.587 1.68c-.479.12-.719.601-.6.96 0 .12.121.239.121.239l4.429 5.521c.121.239.241.481.241.601l-.479 7.32c0 .484.36.841.719.841.121 0 .24 0 .36-.119l6.229-2.642c.114 0 .232-.112.351-.117.118.005.236.117.351.117l6.229 2.642c.118.119.237.119.358.119.359 0 .719-.357.719-.841l-.479-7.32c0-.119.12-.361.241-.601l4.429-5.521s.121-.119.121-.239c.12-.36-.121-.84-.6-.96zm24 0l-6.587-1.68a1.716 1.716 0 01-.479-.36L84.712.357C84.478.121 84.235.005 84 0c-.235.005-.478.121-.712.356l-3.592 6.122c-.121.12-.24.238-.479.36l-6.587 1.68c-.479.12-.719.601-.6.96 0 .12.121.239.121.239l4.429 5.521c.121.239.241.481.241.601l-.479 7.32c0 .484.36.841.719.841.121 0 .24 0 .36-.119l6.229-2.642c.114 0 .232-.112.351-.117.118.005.236.117.351.117l6.229 2.642c.118.119.237.119.358.119.359 0 .719-.357.719-.841l-.479-7.32c0-.119.12-.361.241-.601l4.429-5.521s.121-.119.121-.239c.12-.36-.121-.84-.6-.96z"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

I'm getting the stars rating from the aria-label attribute of the svg element, so what I do is look for the svg element and then get the value for the aria-label attribute.

My questions is that if I look for the element using the find_elements_by_class_name method it works and I get the result I'm looking for:

```
stars_info = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("TkRkB.d.H0")
```

However, if I try to find the same element using the find_element_by_xpath method, I get a NoSuchElementException:

```
stars_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//svg[@class="TkRkB.d.H0"]')
```

Why does this happen? Before anyone says anything, I have tried the xpath expression with different formats (`TkRkB d H0` instead of `TkRkB.d.H0`, switching the order of single quotes and double quotes", etc.)

Answer (score 1):

[By.CLASS_NAME](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#selenium.webdriver.common.by.By.CLASS_NAME) accepts a single classname. So sending multiple classnames through *`By.CLASS_NAME`* may not be a part of the best practices.

The classnames are considered in the following fashion:

- Within *xpath*: Similar to the HTML DOM, i.e. seperated by a single *space* character, example:

  ```
  //tagname[@class='TkRkB d H0']
  ```
- Within *css_selector*: The classnames are seperated by the dot **`.`** character, example:

  ```
  tagname.TkRkB.d.H0
  ```

---

### Solution

To print the value of the *`aria-label`* attribute you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("svg.TkRkB.d.H0").get_attribute("aria-label"))
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @class='TkRkB d H0']").get_attribute("aria-label"))
  ```